# Should I preserve &#xA; in XML element strings

Tags: c#, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I read XML files that sometimes contain elements like

```
<stringValue>text&#xA;text</stringValue>
```

`XmlReader` returns

```
text\ntext
```

for such strings.

So, when I rewrite the source XML later using `XmlWriter` I don't get the same strings (there is no `&#xA;` in them).

Should I worry about all this or it's fine to allow string to be changed this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would worry about it yes because your manipulating the data. This means if you do a round-trip to the XML document the text formatting wouldn't be the same.

You would need to make sure on saving back out to XML persist the same formatting.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I understand that unwanted change of data is a bad thing, but I am talking about strangely encoded whitespace character here. I guess it might make a difference.

Comment: @Bobrovsky Well I believe the only issue you may run into is manually viewing the XML document, perhaps in a browser, you may lose formatting. If this isn't a concern, then you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

`&#xA;` is the xml encoding for a new line character (\n).  If your XML data has a new line in the text, then this notation is correct and the output from XMLWriter is correct.  If the new line was not in the original XML data, I've been seeing an issue with IE10/IE11 using the XMLHttpRequest object inserting \r\n in the XML data.